# Accessing members of elements of a 2d array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble getting access to the data members of the elements in an array.  I have an array of type gamePiece which is a class I defined in a separate header.  The gamePiece has a string data member "name"  which I need to set from a function in my gameBoard file, a gameBoard being a 2d array of gamePieces.  Whenever I try to run the main program, which calls "readBoard" it stalls when it tries to assign a "name" to one of the gamePieces.  What am I doing wrong?

```
//gamePiece.h file
#ifndef GAMEPIECE_H_INCLUDED
#define GAMEPIECE_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class gamePiece //not a struct b/c there are other functions not included here
{
    public:
        string name;
        int row;
}



//gameBoard.h
class gameBoard
{
    public:

    gamePiece board[][6];
    int foxCount, sheepCount;
    void readBoard(istream& boardFile);
    //void printBoard();
};

//gameBoard.cpp
void gameBoard::readBoard(istream& boardFile)
{
    int tFoxCount = 0;
    int tSheepCount = 0;                                                                    
    gamePiece tBoard[6][6];
    gamePiece tPiece;

    tboard[0][0].name = "Sherry";  

    cout << tboard[0][0].name;
}
```

Comment: you have both `tboard` and `tBoard` in your `readBoard` function. Is that a typo? I would have thought your compiler would have thrown an error - but maybe other code not shown makes the compiler think everything is OK (until you run the code...)

Comment: While trying to make it a minimal example you have removed whatever is causing it. This should run fine except `tBoard` should be `tboard`. Do you a variable named `tboard` in the gameBoard class?

Comment: please define "it stalls".

Comment: the most probable cause is a bug in your code in class gameBoard. you declare a undefined size array gamePiece board[][6]; and the compiler do not know what to  do with it... try to set it to the max value you need and maybe it helps gamePiece board[max][6];